# How can I repeat a resource in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a page resource that uses the page title in the url.

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('page', {
        path: '/:page_id'
    });
});

App.PageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { page_id: model.title};
  }
});
```

That is working fine in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aboFati/1/). However, I would like to have subpages nested in the url like this:

> localhost/#/main_page/sub_page

I tried to make a sub resource ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EnogiZig/1/)), but I'm not sure if it is the right approach.

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('page', {path: '/:page_id'},
                  this.resource('subpage', {path: '/:page_id/:subpage_id'}));
});
```

There are two main problems in my attempt: I have to repeat my page view and it doesn't retain the parent page in the url. I'm getting:

> localhost/#/undefined/sub_page

Am I heading in the right direction? Can this be accomplished with just one resource?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the modifications I've made are in your html and template. Please, don't mash up the Handlebars' link-to helper with classic anchors () and don't change the link-to tagname attribute, or atleast think twice before doing so.
First - move the testData to a globally accessible object, so that you can use it in the menu:

Javascript:

```
App.CustomRoutes = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'single'
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'subpages',
    pages: [{
        id: 3,
        title: 'subpage1'
    }, {
        id: 4,
        title: 'subpage2'
    }, {
        id: 5,
        title: 'subpage3'
    }]
}];
```

Html:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav nav">
  {{#each page in App.CustomRoutes}}
    <li class='menu-item'>
      {{#link-to 'page' page.title}}
        {{page.title}}
        {{#if page.pages}}
          <b class="caret"></b>
        {{/if}}
      {{/link-to}}
      <span class='subpages'>
        <ul>
          {{#each subpage in page.pages}}
            <li>
              {{#link-to 'page.subpage' page.title subpage.title}}
                {{subpage.title}}
              {{/link-to}}
            </li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </span>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Then I fixed your router declaration. When you define nested routes, the third parameter to this.resource() is a function, much alike the function you pass to App.Router.map().

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('page', {path: '/:page_id'},
                  function() { this.route('subpage', {path: '/:subpage_id'});});
});
```

Finally, here are the definitions of your routes. Because Subpage is nested in Page, the route must be called PageSubpageRoute. If it was nested in Foo, it would have been FooSubpageRoute.
NOTE: The this.render() call inside a router, has the following parameters: (, ).

```
App.PageSubpageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var parentModel = this.modelFor('page');
    var res = $.grep(parentModel.pages, function (e) {
          if (e.title == params.subpage_id) {
            return e;
          }
        });
    return res[0];
  },
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { subpage_id: model.title};
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('subpage');
  }
});

App.PageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { page_id: model.title};
  },
    model: function (params) {
        return $.grep(App.CustomRoutes, function (e) {
          if (e.title == params.page_id) {
            return e;
          }
        })[0];
    }
});
```

Here is the code: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OguBuQO/1)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered nesting resources?

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('page', {path: '/:page_id'}, function(){
        this.resource('subpage', {path: '/:subpage_id'});
    });
});
```

This would enable at least the URL structure you asked for, but i am not really sure about your requirements.